# Eclipse RCP: popup menu toggle command with object dependent states

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want have a context menu (right-click) that allows to toggle different states of the clicked object.

In the plugin.xml, I already have a popup menu with commands entries such as:

```
<command
   commandId="...switchDistanceCommand"
   label="30s"
   style="toggle">
      <parameter
         name="...switchDistanceMillis"
         value="30000">
      </parameter>
</command>
```

and a command:

```
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
     <command
           id="....switchDistanceCommand"
           name="Switch Distance">
           <commandParameter
                 id="....switchDistanceMillis"
                 name="Seconds"
                 optional="false">
           </commandParameter>
     </command>
</extension>
```

The handler:

```
<handler
       class="....SwitchDistanceHandler"
       commandId="....switchDistanceCommand">
</handler>
```

The handler class `SwitchDistanceHandler` checks which objects are selected an calls a method on them to switch their state (adding or removing the parametrized value to a List).

So far so good...

However, I want to have my menu entries work as checkboxes (as `style="toggle"`) indicates. Every tutorial on this issue (such as [this one](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/03/commands-part-6-toggle-radio-menu.html)) explains how to add a state to command by adding the following code to the plugin.xml:

```
<state 
     class="org.eclipse.ui.handlers.RegistryToggleState:true" 
     id="org.eclipse.ui.commands.toggleState"> 
</state>
```

But this will only give me only **one global state** for this command, I want to read the state(s) from the clicked objects? How can I do this?

**Edit 1:** Copied the wrong code snipped from the tutorial. Also I tried to implement an own class that extends the `State` class (as `RegistryToggleState` does). But I could not figure out how to return a state from this class.

**Edit 2:** I found a workaround. It does not solve the proposed problem but it works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround

This is not *exactly* a solution to the problem because it does not use any state objects. But it works fine for me:
Following the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506062/programatically-change-icon-for-a-eclipse-rcp-command) I implemented  `IElementUpdater` in my Handler. 
In the `updateElement` method, I fetched the selected element(s) from the `element` object and called `element.setChecked()`accordingly.